# Angular *ngFor devmode TypeError: a[getSymbolIterator(...)]

Tags: angular

I'm on angular 6.1.7 and I keep having this error when I use `*ngFor` with arrays on debug mode:

```
AddressEditComponent.html:36 ERROR TypeError: a[getSymbolIterator(...)] is not a function
    at areIterablesEqual (core.js:5492)
    at devModeEqual (core.js:5421)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7689)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10552)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10541)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:11144)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11072)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AddressEditComponent.html:37)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10440)
```

**Where my html is simply :**

```
<select name="country" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="address.country" >
    <option value="">- Pays -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value={{country}}>
        {{country}}
    </option>
</select>
```

countries is `['France','another','another...']`

It stops in production since I use `enableProdMode();`

Any solution ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You will need to add the code about how to get ``countries`` at least.

Comment: it's a simple this.countries = ['France', '...'], but it happens too when I get data from apis.. I tried to reproduce a minimal example on stackblitz but it doesn't throw when it's there.

Comment: and when I try to debug, it looks like getSymbolIterator(...) returns null, do I miss a polyfill or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved when updating to the latest version of angular